# String values passed into SQLite from Ruby/Shoes appear in database as asian characters

Tags: ruby, sqlite, shoes

I am currently learning Ruby/Shoes and Sqlite and am having a weird and (hopefully) straightforward problem. The test program is simple: input a text value into a text box, click "OK" which then writes the value into the table. Unfortunately it seems any text values written into the table appear as an asian character (assuming Chinese) instead of what was input. The test input text was 'Tyler'.

```
  require 'sqlite3'
  Shoes.app do
    db = SQLite3::Database.new ("WPlanning.db")
    testo = edit_line
        button "save" do
    db.execute("create table songlist(title string, number int)")
    db.execute("insert into songlist values(?, 1)", testo.text)
    end
end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your database encoded in UTF-16?  (Run the `PRAGMA ENCODING` command to find out.)

Comment: It confirms UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: It appears the issue is related to SQlite Expert Personal. A command line query returns proper results as well as viewing the data through SQLite Administrator. It would still be nice to get it to display properly as I really like SQLite Expert.

Comment: Dealing with character encoding, keep in mind that you will often mix 3 factors: database input encoding, database output encoding and viewer encoding. Make sure you analyse them all.